# SQL Server Bulk Insert - 0 row(s) affected

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I am trying to do a bulk insert of a `.CSV` from a remote location.

My SQL statement is:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.tblMaster 
FROM '\\ZAJOHVAPFL20\20ZA0004\E\EDData\testbcp.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

My `.CSV` looks like this:

```
john,smith
jane,doe
```

The CSV is saved with UTF-8 encoding, and there is no blank line at the bottom of the file. The table that I am bulk inserting too is also empty.

The table has two columns; `firstname (nvarchar(max))` and `secondname (nvarchar(max))`.

I have `sysadmin` rights on the server so have permission to perform bulk inserts.

When running the SQL, it runs without error, and simple shows -

> 0 row(s) affected

and doesn't insert any information.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.CSV` it means it is Excel sheet, plz confirm.

Comment: I tried your code with sample `.CSV`, and it is working well.

Comment: Hey OP, seems that your SQL server can't see that location across the network, or it can and you lack permissions... Best to speak to your DBA

Answer (score 27):

I know this may be too late to answer but I thought this might help anyone looking for the fix. I had similar issue with Bulk Insert but didn't find any fix online. Most probably the flat/csv file was generated with non-windows format. If you can open the file in Notepad++ then go to edit tab and change the EOL Conversion to "Windows Format". This fixed the problem for me.

**Notepad++>> Edit >> EOL Conversion >> Windows Format**

Comment: This did the trick for me. Cheers!

Comment: ditto :) Great job!

Answer (score 5):

When you specify \n as a row terminator for bulk export, or implicitly use the default row terminator, it outputs a carriage return-line feed combination (CRLF) as the row terminator. If you want to output a line feed character only (LF) as the row terminator - as is typical on Unix and Linux computers - use hexadecimal notation to specify the LF row terminator. For example:
ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A'

no need to do the following:
Notepad++>> Edit >> EOL Conversion >> Windows Format

Comment: This solution, specifically the  ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A',  worked to import Google Earth Engine to SqlServer when the GEE files were csv format.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I opened the CSV with Excel and hit Control + S to resave it. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the file using [`bcp.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) first, see if you get any row or any error. The problem with

```
BULK INSERT ...
FROM '\\REMOTE\SHARE\...'
```

is that you're now bringing impersonation and delegation security into picture and is more difficult to diagnose the issue. When you access a remote share like this you are actually doing a 'double-hop' Kerberos impersonation (aka. delegation) and you need special security set up. Read [Bulk Insert and Kerberos](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2012/09/07/bulk-insert-and-kerberos/) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, at least in part, the UTF-8 encoding. That is not supported by default. If you are using SQL Server 2016 then you can specify Code Page 65001 (i.e. add `, CODEPAGE = '65001'` to the `WITH` clause). If using an earlier version of SQL Server, then you need to first convert the file encoding to UTF-16 Little Endian  (known as "Unicode" in the Microsoft universe). That can be done either when saving the file or by some command line utility.